# Understanding てからだって

Tags: grammar

> ……こっちに来**てからだって**、嫌になったらいつでも全部放り出して壁の向こうに帰れるんだ。仲間面される度にむかむかしたよ。安い同情ごっこにいつ飽きて帰るかってみんなで賭けてた」

86─エイティシックス─
安里アサト

How should I make sense of the bold からだって? I think てから means "after" and だって is でも, which means "even if". Do I get it right?

Comment: I think you got the gist of it.

Comment: Related  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/50296/45489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this から is "after; since; from".

This だって is a colloquial and emphatic topic marker which means "also; even" (but not "even if"). It's interchangeable with も or すら. See: [Why can だって have so many meanings?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43239/5010)

> こっちに来てからだって
> = こっちに来てからも
>
> **Even** after [they] come here, ...