# I can't identify this form (だって)

Tags: grammar

> Xは、この学校で日本語を勉強したん**だって**。

Is this the -te form of the copula?
Haven't encountered it so far.

Comment: It is an indirect form: this is a real useful article on this topic in my opinion http://maggiesensei.com/2012/05/07/direct-indirect-speech-%EF%BC%86%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6tte/ In this particular sentence, you use って to indicate that you have heard (from X him/herself) that X studied Japanese language in school.
Edit: also, this is the form here 勉強したんだ  (article: http://maggiesensei.com/2010/09/08/request-lesson-when-and-how-to-use-%E3%82%93n-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E2%86%92%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%EF%BC%89/ ) In the construction (~)って

Comment: Oops I can't edit my comment anymore, but what I meant to say was 
that the sentence also has the grammar (verb)-んだ and that I thought maybe that article might also be of use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

って is used as a quotative particle in casual speech. See: [と、て、って　Quoting Particle Usage](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3913/5010)

A sentence can sometimes end with と/って, and it usually means "I heard ～" or "They say ～". So you can think that 言ってた or 聞いた is omitted after it.

The sentence means "I heard X learned Japanese at this school."